# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore"

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

When I try to build with Unity cloud build, I got this message:

and then

```
>     Installing cocoapods dependencies:
>64201:        ! .xcworkspace file could not be found.
>64202:        Analyzing dependencies
>64203:        [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
>64204:          In Podfile:
>64205:            Firebase/Analytics (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64206:              Firebase/Core (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64207:                FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.2) was resolved to 6.1.2, which depends on
>64208:                  FirebaseCore (~> 6.3)
>64209:        
>64210:            Firebase/Auth (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64211:              Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64212:                FirebaseCore (= 6.3.0)
>64213:        
>64214:            Firebase/Auth (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64215:              FirebaseAuth (~> 6.2.3) was resolved to 6.2.3, which depends on
>64216:                FirebaseCore (~> 6.2)
>64217:        
>64218:        CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":
>64219:          In Podfile:
>64220:            Firebase/Analytics (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64221:              Firebase/Core (= 6.9.0) was resolved to 6.9.0, which depends on
>64222:                FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.2) was resolved to 6.1.2, which depends on
>64223:                  GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.1.2)
>64224:        
>64225:            Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.42.1) was resolved to 7.42.2, which depends on
>64226:              GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 5.7)
```

and then

```
/BUILD_PATH/jeko.lazaramobile1.appstore-ios/temp20200309-7398-19hbpik/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.h:5:9: 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found`
```

my local builds failed too with missing "GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h"

on my Mac when I check my pod file it looks like :

```
    target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.5'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.5'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.5'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.9.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.42.1'
end
```

I can't figure out what has to be done here. Any help shall be appreciated greatly. I figure out that somehow my firebese.core is stuck to 6.2 or 6.3, but 6.9 is needed. I read that I have to include some framework search path, but this is a manual approach and not the cocoa pod way and I don't know where manually to enter the path.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete Pods/ folder
2. Delete Podfile.lock
3. pod install

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version specifiers from the Podfile or at least be less restrictive.

Both `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` and `Firebase/Analytics` depend on `GoogleAppMeasurement` and the versions specified are incompatible.

Comment: do you mean to remove just the " ~>" from "pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.42.1'" or the whole line? Should I try to remove '6.9.0" from firebase lines?  Can you purpose how it should look?

Comment: Remove the comma and everything after it from each `pod` line - like `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'`