# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod FirebaseCore In snapshot (Podfile.lock):

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting below error for command `pod install`, not resolved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677421/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebasecore)

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseCore (= 3.6.0, ~> 3.6)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Crashlytics was resolved to 6.15.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 4.0.0-beta.1) was resolved to 4.0.0-beta.1, which depends on
        FirebaseCore (>= 6.3.2, ~> 6.3)

    Google/Analytics was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      Google/Core (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.2) was resolved to 3.9.0, which depends on
          FirebaseCore (~> 3.6)
```

Here is my Podfile,

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~>5.15.1'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~>5.15.1'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~>5.15.1'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  target 'MyProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MyProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand why CocoaPods chooses which dependencies by examining the generated `Podfile.lock` file.

I suspect the issue is related to using the deprecated `Google` pod. Likely, you should use `GoogleAnalytics` without the slash instead.

Comment: what happens if I use both FirebaseAnalytics and GoogleAnalytics? Will the data come to a single dashboard?